# How to run Chart.js samples using source code

Tags: chart.js

I would be interested in making a contribution to Chart.js.  I'm looking for a way to **run samples using the original source code** from a cloned repository so that I could be able to see any changes in action.

Is there a way to do this?

The [Building and Testing](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/docs/developers/contributing.md#building-and-testing) section of Chart.js contribution doc mentions how to lint/build/test.  I'm looking for a way to "serve" the samples and see any changes I make "live" from there.

Comment: Take a look at the npm link command https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link

Answer (score 0):

There is a gulp command to run a server (`gulp server`, which serves the root directory on http://localhost:8000) and an other to watch any changes made to the source files to then re-build a bundle js file (`gulp default`).  I ran both these in separate terminals. These are not documented (I found them looking at the gulpfile.js).

The samples, such as http://localhost:8000/samples/charts/bar/vertical.html, include the uncompressed bundle that gets automatically changed every time a modification is made in any source file:

```
<script src="../../../dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
```

The bundle takes around 5secs to complete and after that reloading the sample page makes you see the changes.

This is not exactly what I was looking for, but for making small changes it should do just fine.